# Uploaded file's filepath node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I uploaded a file in node using the

> Input type:"file"

The object generated by the Input field is as follows

```
{
  lastModified: 1524895591000
  lastModifiedDate: Date 2018-04-28T06:06:31.000Z
  name: "images.jpeg"
  size: 10732
  type: "image/jpeg"
  webkitRelativePath: ""
}
```

How do I get the full path to the file in node? I am on a **ubuntu 17.10**

**Update**:

I basically need the full path for the file `FileToBeUploaded.txt`, Which will be something like

> /home/m/Desktop/FileToBeUploaded.txt

So I can execute a child process command on the file Path of the uploaded file.

Comment: You mean so you can "read" the file from the node application? It depends on what is being used to accept the file upload. Different libraries have different means, and different options.

Comment: To give a better explanation.

On the front end I am just using the input tag to choose the file.
On my backend server I am using express-fileupload to read and upload the selected file into the server

What I need is the current path the uploaded file is in. All the uploaded files are in the local file system and are not being uploaded from outside

Comment: [express-fileupload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload) keeps file content in a buffer. As per the documentation all details are accessible from `req.files`. But "buffer" implementations have a limit on how much data they will keep, so larger uploads are truncated. Probably not useful for anything but very small attachments. In short, "there is no filename". It's in memory and referenced from the property specified in the documentation.

Comment: Apologies, I am a but confused. Should I use something else to be able to get the uploaded filepath?

Comment: It depends on what you actually want. We don't know because you have not told us why you think you need this. Perhaps you should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50094981/edit) and actually explain to us all what exactly your reasoning is and what you want to do with this "file path".

Comment: Can not Use something like `multer` in server-side and that will give you the full path?